# .vscode-server folder taking up lots of space

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VScode for web development and noticed that the `.vscode-server` in my user folder is taking up a lot of space (100s of MB). I tried removing it and reopening VSCode and connecting to the server, and the folder comes back and is still quite large. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I also have this problem. 2 Gigabytes. And, for example, `/.vscode-server/bin` contains 10 copies of the `node`, 44 Megabytes each, 9 of them identical.

Answer (score 3):

That's the folder which contains all the extension you install on the server side.
Therefore, if you want to use vs code, better keep it.